# Eclipse v4.5 without delta-pack: How to perform a multiplatform headless PDE build?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, eclipse-mars

Now that eclipse 4.5 is out and the eclipse team decided to not build the so-called "delta-pack" anymore, I don'tknow how to perform a PDE headless build with ant..

Official PDE build documentation here http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?nav=%2F4_2_0
states that variable "baseLocation" should point to "the location of an eclipse install containing all the pre-built features and plug-ins that your product requires in features/ and plugins/ subdirectories"

With v4.4, it was easy, this variable was pointing to the location of the unzipped delta-pack with all the platform specific stuff

But with v4.5, how to obtain/setup this "location of an eclipse install containing all the pre-built features and plug-ins..." ?

Here https://wiki.eclipse.org/Building , it is explained the "Preferred way of doing multi-platform builds", this is for build from eclipse only, not headless builds and this does not create a structure with features/plugins required for the multiplatform build anywhere.

So I don't know how to set the "baseLocation" variable to in my build...

Thx

(FYI, tycho is not -yet- an option for us..)

Comment: Go back to Eclipse 4.4.

Comment: You didn't read the question. Downgrading to v4.4 will obviously not help us building our app with v4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "Building" wiki page also describes how to "roll your own" delta pack.

I just added that description, and ant script, last night, 6/24. I think that example script produce a better Delta Pack than what is in the R-4.5-201506032000 directories. I'd be interested in hearing of user experiences, say in Eclipse bug 470913.

[And, admit, I still "owe" the community an example of doing a headless build, for previous delta pack users, but it will center around doing a p2 oriented build. There place to begin reading about that is in the Eclipse Help, search for "p2 builds" and "fetching from repositories". ]

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try in the coming days. I still don't understand why the delta-pack is not build part of the eclipse build...and yes the doc at http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?nav=%2F4_2_0 should definitively be updated to be directly usable, or totally removed in favor of it seems the more "official" wat to build: tycho (which is way overkill in our case and needs the knowledge of maven an internet connection to build)

Comment: I was able to build the DP with the script there :http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git/plain/scripts/createdeltapack.xml . However I hitted this: http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/12/14/running-p2-ant-tasks-in-eclipse/. Maybe it would be a good idea to add this link to the script , at leat for newbies like me that do knoe nothing of p2 stuff. The result of the script was the exact same result of the dp download from aCodingBee" link so yes the script works

Comment: Another thing, in this script, ine the assembler target, the <exec executable="zip" .. task should be replaces by the <zip task... IMHO

Comment: @titou10, please post suggestions for improvements to Eclipse bug 470913.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the eclipse mars delta pack from eclipse here:
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/eclipse-4.5-delta-pack.zip

Comment: Hi Jorg,  I didn't find DP.

Comment: @ShivendraPrakashShukla it looks like delta pack is now removed completely and not provided anymore, you'll have to define the appropriate software site into your target definition

Comment: I tried, but I didn't the appropriate software site. If you have any idea, Please suggest me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ShivendraPrakashShukla this depends on your target version - for example if you want to run on Mars release use http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5 or if you need Oxygen use http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7

Answer (score 1):

Deltapack is removed from 4.5.1 officially as per the below bug.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480149

You can build multi-platform builds using the following wiki.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Building#Multi-platform_build

Comment: Sorry, but I did not find "Include all environments". Previously, I did [export => product](https://sourceforge.net/p/zamiacad/wiki/HowToRelease/#1-create-a-product). It ends up with `Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.equinox.executable: Unable to find plug-in: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417` regardless I followed installed the  http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 or not. Probably because  I could not find "Include all environments" option there.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov in your target definition, you have to add the software site for your targeted version - e.g. http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5 when you want to use Mars release - once that is resolved, you will have a second page in your product export wizard where you can select all platforms you want to build