# Eclipse v4.7.2 without delta-pack: How to perform a multiplatform headless PDE build?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

Now that eclipse 4.7.2 is out and the eclipse team decided to not build the so-called "delta-pack" anymore, I don'tknow how to perform a PDE headless build with ant..

Official PDE build documentation here http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?nav=%2F4_2_0
states that variable "baseLocation" should point to "the location of an eclipse install containing all the pre-built features and plug-ins that your product requires in features/ and plugins/ subdirectories"

Answer (score 0):

Delta pack is no more produced since v4.5, Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036996/eclipse-v4-5-without-delta-pack-how-to-perform-a-multiplatform-headless-pde-bui)
The official build tool is now eclipse tycho: https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php