# problem to export from eclipse 64 to 32 with delta pack

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, delta-pack

**EDIT: I found the mistake, this can be closed. I need point to the jre of 32 bits from export folder.**

I am using the eclipse 64 bits photon version to develop an rcp application, i wanna export an 32 bits rcp using the delta pack plugin.

The export is successful but when i run the .exe there is an error

```
!SESSION 2019-03-14 10:17:20.669 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2019-03-14 10:17:20.902
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-03-14 10:17:20.903
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.3.0.v20180502-1828.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2019-03-14 10:17:20.905
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-03-14 10:17:20.905
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
```

Somebody know this issue or something releated to this

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: We can't help until you tell us the exact messages you are getting.

Comment: Eclipse photon is v4.8.Delta-pack is no more available since v4.5, replaced by eclipse tycho. . check this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480149 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036996/eclipse-v4-5-without-delta-pack-how-to-perform-a-multiplatform-headless-pde-bui and this https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php

Comment: Hi, i just update the question.

Comment: @titou10 when i export to 64 bits works, i will check the info that you provided. Thanks

Comment: I found the mistake, this can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others who might come across this question, I'll just point out that your transcript shows that you are trying to load bundles that require at least Java 8 (aka 1.8) but you're running on a Java 7 JVM (aka 1.7).

```
!SESSION 2019-03-14 10:17:20.669 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0
[...]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
```